# Removing Controls from Form (Doesn't hit every Control I want to remove)

Tags: c#, forms, controls, dynamically-generated

I am dynamically adding some Controls to my Form and it works quite well but when I want to remove them again, it only removes a few of them in a weird (random) pattern (2 controls here, 2 there,...).

I tried using:

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls.OfType<Control>())
        {
            if (item.Tag == "potentiallyRemove")
                this.Controls.Remove(item);
        }
```

And yes the controls I want to remove have all set the "Tag" Attribute.

I also tried to remove only the PictureBoxes:

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
        {              
                this.Controls.Remove(item);
        }
```

I don't want to use `this.Controls.Clear()` because I have an heading line which i don't want to remove.

Is this a bug or something like that and if yes, is there any workaround?

Comment: You are modifying a collection that you are iterating through, are you also doing this from an event (like a button click)?

Comment: Sorry I don't really know what you mean^^
I am adding events to some buttons but how could that be a problem?

Comment: Oh and the function to remove the controls is triggered by an event handler of an dynamically added button.
And this one should also be removed...
Could that be a problem?
EDIT: I tried to trigger the function by a button which should not be removed but it's the same result...

Comment: You are modifying the collection you are iterating, that's bad.  Use `this.Controls.OfType<Control>().ToList()` instead so you are iterating a copy of the collection.  And do keep in mind that calling the Dispose() method of the controls you remove is a rock-hard requirement.  It is **not** optional for the Control class.

Comment: Are the controls all sitting directly on the form? If not you may have to use a tiny recursion to reach them all.. See my answer!

Comment: Yes the controls are all sitting directly on the form.
I am adding them with `this.Controls.Add(myControl)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid errors: Add the controls to an array and then remove them.

try this:

```
    List<Control> controlsToBeRemoved = new List<Control>();
    foreach (Control item in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
    {
        controlsToBeRemoved.Add(item);
    }

    foreach (Control item in controlsToBeRemoved)
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(item);
    }
```

Comment: Great thanks your version worked for me!
Modifying the collection i am iterating through isn't the best idea :P